# Does any cards care about the color of mana spent on other spells/abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are plenty of cards, such as cards with *Sunburst* and *Converge* and most of [these](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+%5B%22was%20spent%20to%20cast%22%5D) cards, which care about the colors of mana spent *on themselves*.

Additionally, [Nix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nix) cares about whether or not *any* mana was spent on its target, but doesn't care about what color(s) it was.

Are there any cards that care about *what color(s)* of mana
were spent on something *other than the card which cares*?

As a concrete example, suppose I tapped a Mountain and [Temple Garden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Temple%20Garden) to cast [Roast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Roast). Can it ever matter whether the [Temple Garden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Temple%20Garden) was tapped for G or W, i.e. whether Roast was cast for GR or WR?

Comment: You are asking two different questions there. The question in the last sentence has a very different answer than the one in your title. Please clarify.

Comment: Not sure if you're trying to be sarcastic or why, but no, it doesn't. And my complaint about the question in the last line still applies. Tapping a land for mana and paying costs are very different things, even though they usually happen in the same context of casting a spell or activating an ability.

Comment: I was wondering if your comment was due to you interpreting "else" differently from what I'd intended. ​ (I'm using that for "other than the thing on which the mana was spent".) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: so to try and clarify, you are asking "Are there any instances where "Card A" cares how much/what type of mana whas spent to cast "Card B"?

Comment: @thatdude1087 : ​ ​ ​ I mentioned Nix, which cares whether "no mana was spent to cast" card B. ​ Additionally, there are lots are cards that [care about their target's CMC](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+[spell]+[%22with%20converted%20mana%20cost%22]), and thus how much was spent on Xs in their target's mana cost. ​ Otherwise, that's pretty much correct. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I think that rewording the "concrete example" at the end can fix some of the clarity issues people are seeing. Would it be accurate to say that what you wanted to know there can be expressed as "Can it ever matter whether I spent {W}{R} or {G}{R} to cast Roast?"

Comment: The question seems reasonable enough to me; tried to edit to make it even more clear.

Comment: I sure hope not, what a colossal hassle and judging disaster it would be to have such a card in a format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not what you are looking for but in a way it might fit the description.
If [Illusionary Mask](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusionary%20Mask) is used to cast a creature then that creature spell cares about what colors are used on the Mask's ability.

Otherwise I don't think anything else comes even remotely close, but of course it's very hard to prove that something doesn't exist.

Anyway, i searched for cards that either had the word "spend" or "spent" in the text and checked them one by one, because I think that if such a card existed it should have one of those words

Comment: Ice Cauldron might also fit, in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "care".

There are abilities that remember what colors of mana were spent to activate them, such as the abilities of [Illusionary Mask](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIllusionary%20Mask%5d) and [Ice Cauldron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIce%20Cauldron%5d) (credit to [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/29238/6692) and its comments).

There is at least one spell allows you to cast another spell based on the number of colors used to cast it: [Bring to Light](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBring%20to%20Light%5d).

There are also indirect effects. Although things like Sunburst only directly affect the card with Sunburst, other spells could depend on attributes of the Sunburst card which in turn depend on the color(s) of mana spent to cast it. For example:

> *Situation A*
>
> - Cast [Arcbound Wanderer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcbound%20Wanderer%5d) for {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}{G}.
> - Cast [Devour Flesh](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDevour%20Flesh%5d), targeting yourself.
>
> You gain 5 life.
>
> *Situation B*
>
> - Cast Arcbound Wanderer for {G}{G}{G}{G}{G}{G}
> - Cast Devour Flesh, targeting yourself.
>
> You gain 1 life.

There are zero spells currently in existence that do the following:

- "If you/the controller of the spell spent [color] to cast [some other spell], [effect]."
- "Whenevever you cast a spell, if you spent [color] to cast it, [effect.]"

Comment: I don't think you're using "care" in the same sense as the question. This doesn't care about the color of the mana, it cares about something that happened because of the mana. I don't think people would generally say that Devour Flesh cares about what Master Biomancer's power was when your creature entered the battlefield because that'd affect the number of +1/+1 counters on them and therefore its toughness. Devour Flesh just cares about your creature's toughness now, not how it came to have that toughness.

Comment: @Jefromi I see your point. I will modify my answer to clarify.

Comment: @Jefromi There we go. Does that look better?

Comment: Yeah, it's better. Honestly I wouldn't bother with the Arcbound Wanderer example all, because it seems quite clearly *not* what the OP means by "care". I think the bits after that are the actual answer, and that's just a digression, but keep it if you think it's useful!

Comment: @Jefromi I want that part of the answer because it was my first impression of what the OP was asking for, but after a more careful reading, I can see why your view is also reasonable. So I compromised and moved the part I like closer to the bottom of the answer. Now the part you liked more is up top.

Comment: Cool. For what it's worth, it might be clearer to say "spells whose outcome depends on things which depend on the colors you used to cast other spells"; although you've changed "care about" to "depend on", it still implies a direct connection while you're using it to describe something definitely indirect. And when you allow connections that indirect, almost any conditional effect in the game depends on almost anything else, because you'll be able to find some chain of dependencies which form that connection.

Comment: @Jefromi Can you make the edit? I'm not totally sure I understand what you are saying, but it sounds like a minor edit and something I will probably agree with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36760/discussion-between-jefromi-and-rainbolt).

Answer (score 1):

Addressing specifically:

> "Can it ever matter whether the Temple Garden was tapped for G or W?"

Because that is substantively different from:

> Are there any cards that care about what color(s) of mana were spent on something other than the card which cares?

Yes, there are cards that cares about the mana a source produces:

[Gauntlet of Power](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gauntlet%20of%20Power) and [Caged Sun](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Caged%20Sun).

Comment: Okay, I was unsure before, but this answer tipped me over the edge. The question is definitely unclear.

Comment: @BrainLot By design.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, Gauntlet of Power doesn't care what colors of mana were spent. It cares what colors of mana were produced. I don't think that technically satisfies the second quoted question in your answer. Same goes for Caged Sun.

Comment: @Rainbolt Preceding the edit, the Question posed two disparate concepts; each is highlighted by the blocked text in this Answer. I addressed the portion that has been phased out of the Question.

Comment: Now that the question has been edited to clarify that this is not what they were asking for, this answer is pretty much completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are also cycles in Eventide (e.g. [Batwing Brume](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Batwing%20Brume)) and the original Ravnica block (e.g. [Azorius Herald](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Azorius%20Herald)) that care about using specific colors of mana to cast spells.

Comment: Both of those cards are already linked in the question.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Oh, I didn't notice that link <<;;;;